# What is land area under house called besides the whole land?

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for the term which is used to specify the Land Area occupied by the house only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that might be the [*footprint*](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_definition_of_a_building_footprint).

> [FOOTPRINT](http://www.ralphjoneshomeplans.com/NEW%20MAIN%20PAGES/footprint-plot-plan_info.htm) OF A HOUSE IN RELATION TO THE BUILDING LOT:
>
> The Footprint of a house is the dimensions of the total covered area
>   of the home including garages and porches.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the land, it can be called 'floor space'; in terms of the building, you might call it the 'plinth area' or 'builtup area'.

Comment: Isn't floor space closer to carpet space? But I like 'plinth area', it sounds nice and architectural. Upvoted for that.

Comment: Yes. There's a 'marginal' difference. Floor Space is the interior (carpet) area, Plinth Area or Built-up Area includes the area under wall thickness -- so in effect it's the total area under the external margin.

Answer (score 0):

Footprint is a good answer, but I have also seen 'ground floor area', which excludes covered patios and similar as it is measured from the building walls, and 'building coverage' which includes exterior structures such as balconies, covered carports, and the like, and also the perimeter of the basement.